# MongoDB C# Driver does not automap pascal-cased properties

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using the official MongoDB C# driver to query an existing collection of documents that use camel-cased property names e.g. `post.title`.

[The docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-csharp-driver/#getting-started-with-csharp-driver) seem to suggest that nothing is required to map the documents to C# POCOs with pascal-cased property names e.g:

```
public class Post
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string[] Tags { get; set; }
}
```

However, when attempting to query the collection I get the exception:

> Element 'title' does not match any field or property of class MongoDBDemo.Post.

If change `Post.Title` to `Post.title` the query executed successfully.

Is there a way to tell the driver to deserialize to pascal-cased properties and serialize to camel-cased properties by default?

Comment: Is there nothing that can be customised [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/) ?

Comment: @NeilLunn That link seems to have changed. Is [this](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/reference/bson/serialization/) what you were referring to? Also, the link in the OP also have changed. Can you update it Ben Foster?

Answer (score 8):

I know this is pretty old, but I found that the following can be used to map the camelCased fields in documents to PascalCased properties in C# POCOs:

```
var conventionPack = new ConventionPack
{
    new CamelCaseElementNameConvention()
};

ConventionRegistry.Register(
    name: "CustomConventionPack", 
    conventions: conventionPack,
    filter: t => true);
```

For filter I am using `t => true` so that this camelCase convention applies to all my entities/collections.

Advantage of this approach over using `BsonElement` attribute is that this approach can be used in cases when entities/POCOs do not reside in the same project as the one having mongodb driver reference in it (e.g. in repository pattern, or in the clean architecture).

Read more from the official documentation [here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/reference/bson/mapping/conventions/).

Answer (score 4):

The docs actually say the opposite:

> Normally the name of the field in the database is exactly the same as
>   the name of the field or property in your domain class, but Id is an
>   exception and is mapped to _id in the database.

You could investigate creating your own [`Convention`](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/#conventions) to override the names and make a Pascal based naming scheme. You could have it be automatically applied to every class you use with MongoDb for example.

Or, you could manually specify new names either through attributes:

```
public class Post {
    [BsonElement("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Or, the class map:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Post>(cm => {
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.GetMemberMap(c => c.Title).SetElementName("title");
});
```

Comment: Did he change the question? Your answer doesn't even address his issue.

Comment: Yes, it does in fact. You can create a convention, or use an attribute, or a class map to adjust the case of a field in C#.

Comment: The links seem to have changed. Can you please update them? I would have done it myself, but just want to make sure I didn't change anything? One quick Q: is there any way to automate this for all the entities I have?

Comment: @WiredPrairie Never mind, I have found the answer to my question, and added an answer of my own in this thread :-)

Answer (score -1):

Add an attribute to the properties would do the trick:

```
public class Post
{

    [BsonElement("_id")]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Also, if you have anything in the database that doesn't exist in your class, add the attribute

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements(true)]
```

to avoid getting the previous error message.

There are some other attributes in the namespace MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes. Find the [document here](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.1/html/7c3829d2-ad42-6bbc-40c6-c2adca36078b.htm).

Comment: Did he change the question? Your answer doesn't even address his issue.